# Pandoc produces errors when using quotation marks with `lang: hu`

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, xelatex, typesetting

MWE:

```
---
lang: hu
---

"Test quotation"
```

If I run `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf`, I get the following error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.66 `
```

This seems to happen because of the Hungarian language setting. How do I avoid this? If I remove `lang: hu` from the YAML block, `pandoc` succeeds in building the pdf file, but of course with English quotation marks. I would like to have localised, Hungarian quotation marks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because pandoc is using pdfTeX by default, not XeLaTeX. Specify your preferred engine by adding the option `--pdf-engine=xelatex` to your pandoc call. (The option was named `--latex-engine=xelatex` before pandoc 2.)

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't solve this myself... Thank you! One more little question: why do I have to type quotes like this: ,,quote" instead of "quote"? In Hungarian, quotation marks look like the first one, but isn't the point of using 'lang' in the YAML block that these are automatically converted?

Comment: Pandoc's Markdown parser has no internationalization support as of now.  The `lang` attribute only afffects the writers, i.e., LaTeX output in this case. Allowing to alter the parser by setting the attr is a non-trivial problem.

Comment: The respective pandoc issue is https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/661

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is too old question, but online search led me here, so here is mine solution that generates PDF with correct localized quotes.

```markdown
---
lang: hu
---

"Test quotation"

"Another test quotation"
```

With this command:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -o example.pdf example.md
```

it generates PDF with wrong quotations:

```
“Test quotation”
“Another test quotation”
```

But given you have [csquotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) installed, this document:

```markdown
---
lang: hu
csquotes: true
---

"Test quotation"

"Another test quotation"
```

using same command as above generates PDF with correct quotations now:

```
„Test quotation”
„Another test quotation”
```